# How to initialize on MVC module?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC programming.  In normal OOP, where I have my class, I would just initiliaze and load data from database.  In MVC, we have modules, how do I load up records from it?

Here is my current code for type UserAcount:

```
[Table("UserAccount")]
public class UserAccount {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int companyID { get; set; }
}
```

Say that I have an user with name "testUser", how do I initialize on this record and get it's information?  How do I do this:

```
UserAccount user = new UserAccount("tesetUser");
```

How and where shoulud I use this?

```
user = user.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userName.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). This is the default ORM that MVC uses. Simply:

1. If you don't have a project context, yet, create one:

   ```
   public class MyProjectContext : DbContext
   {
       public MyProjectContext()
           : base("name=ConnectionStringNameHere")
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add your models to your project context:

   ```
   public class MyProjectContext : DbContext
   {
       ...

       public DbSet<SomeModel> SomeModels { get; set; }
       public DbSet<SomeOtherModel> SomeOtherModels { get; set; }
       # etc.
   }
   ```
3. Update your database using Package Manager Console (TOOLS > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console):

   ```
   > update-database
   ```

(hit ENTER after typing that)

Now, to use your context in your controllers:

```
public class MyAwesomeController : Controller
{
    private MyProjectContext db = new MyProjectContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var someModels = db.SomeModels;
        return View(someModels);
    }

    public ActionResult GetSomeModel(int id)
    {
        var someModel = db.SomeModels.Find(id);
        return View(someModel);
    }

    # other actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, you should do this logic in your controller, which will pass the data to the view. However, MVC is meant for UI separation of concerns, so theoretically you should be doing this in your domain layer, which is called from your controller.

[Here is a decent article from Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html), however I disagree that the controller is the brains of the application. It is more of the brains of the UI...but that depends on how complex your code is. Dont create a domain layer if it is stupidly simple

Answer (score 0):

In the MVC model, Controllers are responsible for processing HTTP requests.

Typically you would load your entity (e.g. UserAccount) in a controller action.

If you want to edit / update an entity, typically you would map the relevant fields to a model that reflects the UserAccount.  A separate model is suggested because the needs of the UI are often somewhat different than the needs of the entity model.  Having separate classes for each concern avoids polluting the entity model to satisfy the needs of the view.

Comment: How exactly do you:  "load your entity (e.g. UserAccount) in a controller action"?  Specifically in my case, the UserAccount Module?